# python join equivalent

Tags: python, join

I have a dictionary say..

```
dict = {
    'a' : 'b',
    'c' : 'd'
}
```

In php I would to something like implode ( ',', $dict ) and get the output 'a,b,c,d'
How do I do that in python?

Comment: Dictionaries in Python are unordered. Just thought you'd want to know.

Comment: And for the record, I don't understand the downvotes. This is a legitimate question with a fascinating answer.

Comment: @Ignacio - I wonder too. My motivation to answer below was to answer the question. I'd understand downvotes if my (identified as inelegant) answer was wrong. sigh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be easiest way:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = dict(a='b', c='d')
>>> ','.join(chain(*a.items()))
'a,b,c,d'
```

Comment: you don't need the list() in there

Comment: to avoid creating intermediate lists: `','.join(chain.from_iterable(a.iteritems()))`

Answer (score 5):

First, the **wrong** answer:

```
','.join('%s,%s' % i for i in D.iteritems())
```

This answer is wrong because, while associative arrays in PHP *do* have a given order, dictionaries in Python *don't*. The way to compensate for that is to either use an ordered mapping type (such as `OrderedDict`), or to force an explicit order:

```
','.join('%s,%s' % (k, D[k]) for k in ('a', 'c'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use string [join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) on a flattened list of dictionary items like this:

```
",".join(i for p in dict.items() for i in p)
```

Also, you probably want to use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 2):

This has quadratic performance, but if the dictionary is always small, that may not matter to you

```
>>> sum({'a':'b','c':'d'}.items(), ())
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

note that the dict.items() does not preserve the order, so ('c', 'd', 'a', 'b') would also be a possible output

Answer (score 1):

This is not very elegant, but works:

```
result=list()
for ind in g:
   result.append(ind)
   for cval in g[ind]:
       result.append(cval)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[]
[ a.extend([i,j]) for i,j in dict.items() ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
[value for pair in {"a": "b", "c" : "d"}.iteritems() for value in pair]
```

or

```
(lambda mydict: [value for pair in mydict.iteritems() for value in pair])({"a": "b", "c" : "d"})
```

**Explanation:**

Simplified this example is return each value from each pair in the `mydict`

*Edit: Also put a ",".join() around these. I didn't read your question properly*

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it is also good to note.

The original question is misleading. implode() does not flatten an associative array in PHP, it joins the values

```php
echo implode(",", array("a" => "b", "c" => "d"))
// outputs b,d
```

implode() would be the same as

```python
",".join(dict.values())
# outputs b,d
```

Answer (score -1):

dictList = dict.items()

This will return a list of all the items.

Comment: this will return **pairs** of values (tuples or whatever)